# Postgresql indexing lower-case(column) doesn't work as expected?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following is an example of the data I can get when searching for "amadeus" substring:

```
db=# SELECT entidade FROM gma WHERE entidade ILIKE '%amadeus%';
            entidade
---------------------------------
 Hairdresser Amadeus
 Snack-Bar Amadeus
 Restaurant Amadeus
 Restaurant Amadeus
 Restaurant Amadeus
 Amadeus - Musical Instruments
(6 rows)
```

However I want to be able replace `ILIKE` by `LIKE`. So I tried to index `entidade` with only lower-case letters:

```
db=# CREATE INDEX idx_gma_entidade ON gma USING btree
db-#   ( lower(entidade) );
CREATE INDEX
```

By now I was expecting to access exactly the same data using `LIKE`:

```
db=# SELECT entidade FROM gma WHERE entidade LIKE '%amadeus%';
 entidade
----------
(0 rows)
```

But, as you can see, the result is not what I expected... 
Can somebody care to explain why? And, if possible, how can I achieve the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the lower() function on the column when running your select:

`SELECT entidade FROM gma WHERE lower(entidade) LIKE '%amadeus%';`

But because you have a wildcard at the front, the query will never use an index anyway. So there is no point in creating one

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name but... Could you please also explain what's the point of allowing expressions when creating an index? How are those expressions used? If I run `SELECT entidade FROM gma WHERE entidade LIKE 'amadeus%'` will I be using the lower-case index?

Comment: @Andre: no it will not, because the indexed expression is not part of your query. The statement `SELECT entidade FROM gma WHERE lower(entidade) LIKE 'amadeus%';` will use the index

Answer (score 2):

You can't use btree indexes for this. Using a wildcard at the beginning of the search string makes an index useless.

Use full text search or take a look at [wildspeed](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/wildspeed).

Answer (score 1):

Creating an index should never change the *result* of a query, only how it is *implemented*. You must specify ILIKE or a construct such as `lower(column) LIKE '...'` for a case-insensitive match against a text column. You can use the `citext` contrib module to create a citext type that will match case-insensitively by default, which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone pointed out the query was not using your index. You can use explain analyse keywords in front of your query to find whether index was used or not.